# how to not inherit? or how to reset inherited width to the value before?

Tags: css, inheritance

I installed *Thank you plugin* but the button on my [test site](http://asha.onalllevels.com/) looks strange.

I found out why. Because it inherits `#commentform textarea { width: 45%; }` from my theme. If I remove the width from css the button looks ok. Any idea how I can fix that? Of course I do not want to remove width for #commentform textarea. Can I do something about that on css level of the button? Something like `width:not-inherit; width:reset;`  I'd say that the width of the button wouldn't be declared at all if there was no `#commentform textarea`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try putting

```
width: auto;
```

on the button.  That should fix it in this case.

Comment: `width: auto;` looks good. I guess the background image is the trouble thing now. But it should be ok from css point of view. Thank you for that.

Comment: Does this answer implies that we have to know the default value for each property we want to break inherited value ?

Answer (score 6):

It is an old question but I just had the same problem with `width` inherit from parent as 100%. Turns out adding `display` property to `inline-block` helps.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add "!important" to the newer css.

ex :

```
first{ float:right;}
second{ float:left !important;}



<div class="first second"></div>
```

This div should be float left

Comment: `float:left !important;` didn't help. I believe it is about the width

Comment: hehe sorry, the float left was just an exemple to show how to override a previous css, not the solution to your problem :) anyway, you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your css and also remove that inline styling you have there for that button:

```
input.thanks_button{
    background:url("http://asha.onalllevels.com/wp-content/plugins/thanks-you-counter-button/images/thanks_compact_blue1.png") no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    width:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by `remove inline styling`. I tried to remove anything like inline using firebug along with your code and it had no affect. Not sure if I did it right way :-(