# Is there any kind of HTML or CSS that ensures HTML within a DIV doesn't inherit any styling?

Tags: html, css

I am currently restyling a website, but part of the site takes a string from the CMS and puts it into a description area. The description often has its on HTML, such as bullet points.

The problem is the designs we received also use bullet points to style certain aspects, which make everything within this description area styled entirely incorrectly (tiny width for ULs, background applied to H2, etc).

Is there any kind of tag that will reset the styling of everything within it?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I've gone for this solution, which works when I apply the class 'CMSReset'. It resets the main offenders, thanks for the help:

```
div.CMSReset, div.CMSReset *
{
    margin:0pt !important;
    padding:0pt !important;
    vertical-align:baseline !important;
    width:auto !important;
    background:none;
    color:inherit;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the 'Cascading' nature of CSS means that you would need to override all the styles on your child element one way or another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short and simple: no, you'll have to reset the stylings taht need to be reseted on your own.

a workaround would be to use an iframe wich would prevent the inner content against inherited styles, but that solution is even worse in my opinion.

this other topics might also be interesting for you:

- [reset multiple css styles for one single div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974980/reset-multiple-css-styles-for-one-single-div-element)
- [how to not inherit? or how to reset inherited width to the value before? (css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970246/how-to-not-inherit-or-how-to-reset-inherited-width-to-the-value-before-css)

Comment: I was worried that that might be the case. Thanks a lot for confirming though. I will check out the links you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, people override CSS Styles in 2 ways:

1) They define an inline style on the attribute itself so:

```
<div style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></div>
```

Would override any other style.

You can also apply a style via an id (#IdName) which will have precedence

2) They redefine the style at that level of the document. You can use the !important css modifier (but this isn't universally supported).

If you've blanket applied styles, like div or body > div then these can be difficult to override and often require restructuring, or rethinking, your styles and classes.